# Unrecognized token 'Ã¿': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to send a message to Kafka  and consume the same  message from Kafka using Spring cloud stream. I am sending the JSON String { "acctNo" : "32432", "tn" : "3234" } using Postman to the rest controller of my producer. I am getting the JSON Parserexception :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Ã¿': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
    at [Source: [B@776e03af; line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581) ~[jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533) ~[jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3451) ~[jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2610) ~[jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser
```

My code is like this :

**Producer Application yaml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        activationMsgQueue:
          destination: test
          contentType: application/json
```

**Producer Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ActivationQueueService")
public class ActivationQueueController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ActivationQueueController.class);

    @Autowired
    SpringCloudStreamClient producer;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new ActivationDataInfoValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sendMessage", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody @Valid ActivationDataInfo message)
            throws JsonProcessingException {


        LOGGER.debug("Activation Data Request Recieved : " + message.toString());
        if (message != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            producer.sendMessagetoKafka(message);
            LOGGER.info("Activation Data Request sent to Kafka : " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer Code**

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
public class SpringCloudStreamClient {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SpringCloudStreamClient.class);

    @Autowired MessageChannels msgChannel;

    public Object sendMessagetoKafka(ActivationDataInfo msg){
        LOGGER.info("Sending Message : " + msg);
        msgChannel.save().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
        return new String("Success");
    }
}
```

**Consumer Application Yaml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          content-type: application/x-java-object;type=com.comcast.activation.message.vo.ActivationDataInfo
          destination: test
          group: prac
          consumer:
            headerMode: raw
            enableDlq: true
            resetOffsets: true
            startOffset: latest
```

**Consumer Code**

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class LogSink {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogSink.class);

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
    public void loggerSink( ActivationDataInfo payload) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Received: " + payload.getAcctNo());
    }

}
```

**Domain class**

```
public class ActivationDataInfo {

private String acctNo;
private String tn;

public String getAcctNo() {
    return acctNo;
}
public void setAcctNo(String acctNo) {
    this.acctNo = acctNo;
}
public String getTn() {
    return tn;
}
public void setTn(String tn) {
    this.tn = tn;
}
```

What is causing this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `headerMode: raw` from the client, since the producer doesn't use it either.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you Marius. Appreciate it very much.